# Nix Pill 14: How to make callPackage overridable?

Tags: functional-programming, nix, nixos

I am having trouble understanding [Nix Pill 14](https://nixos.org/nixos/nix-pills/override-design-pattern.html#idm140737315729216). The author provides `makeOverridable`, and then challenges the user to integrate it with `callPackage`. `makeOverridable` and `default.nix` are provided, as follows, where `makeOverridable` is in the file `lib.nix`, and `callPackage` is in the file `default.nix`:

```
# file: lib.nix

rec {
  makeOverridable = f: origArgs:
    let
      origRes = f origArgs;
    in
      origRes // { override = newArgs: makeOverridable f (origArgs // newArgs); };
}
```

```
# file: default.nix

let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  allPkgs = nixpkgs // pkgs;
  callPackage = path: overrides:
    let f = import path;
    in f ((builtins.intersectAttrs (builtins.functionArgs f) allPkgs) // overrides);
  pkgs = with nixpkgs; {
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix nixpkgs;
    hello = callPackage ./hello.nix { };
    graphviz = callPackage ./graphviz.nix { };
    graphvizCore = callPackage ./graphviz.nix { gdSupport = false; };
  };
in pkgs
```

This is what I have come up with:

```
# file: default.nix (my implementation)

let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  allPkgs = nixpkgs // pkgs;
  callPackage = path: overrides:
    let
      f = import path;
      origRes = f ((builtins.intersectAttrs (builtins.functionArgs f) allPkgs) // overrides);
    in
      origRes // { override = newArgs: callPackage f (overrides // newArgs); };
  pkgs = with nixpkgs; {
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix nixpkgs;
    hello = import ./hello.nix {};
    graphviz = import ./graphviz.nix {};
    graphvizCore = graphviz.override { gdSupport = false; };
  };
in pkgs
```

I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what is going on here. Could you please provide the correct implementation and explain what I am doing wrong?

EDIT: I managed to get it to work, however, it is still not recursive.

```
# file: default.nix

let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  allPkgs = nixpkgs // pkgs;
  callPackage = path: overrides:
  let
    f = import path;
    origArgs = f ((builtins.intersectAttrs (builtins.functionArgs f) allPkgs) // overrides);
    makeOverridable = { override = newArgs: (origArgs // newArgs); };
  in
    origArgs // makeOverridable;
pkgs = with nixpkgs; rec {
  mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix nixpkgs;
  hello = callPackage ./hello.nix { };
  graphviz = callPackage ./graphviz.nix { };
  graphvizCore = graphviz.override { gdSupport = false; };
};
in pkgs
```

EDIT 2:

```
# file: default.nix

let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  allPkgs = nixpkgs // pkgs;
  makeOverridable = f: origArgs:
    let origRes = f origArgs;
    in origRes // { override = newArgs: makeOverridable f (origArgs // newArgs); };
  callPackage1 = path: overrides:
    let f = import path;
    in f ((builtins.intersectAttrs (builtins.functionArgs f) allPkgs) // overrides);
  callPackage = makeOverridable callPackage1;
  pkgs = with nixpkgs; {
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix nixpkgs;
    hello = callPackage ./hello.nix { };
    graphviz = callPackage ./graphviz.nix { };
    graphvizCore = graphviz.override { gdSupport = false; };
  };
in pkgs
```

SOLUTION:

```
# file: default.nix

let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  allPkgs = nixpkgs // pkgs;
  makeOverridable = f: origArgs:
    let origRes = f origArgs;
    in origRes // { override = newArgs: makeOverridable f (origArgs // newArgs); };
  callPackage1 = path: overrides:
    let f = import path;
    in f ((builtins.intersectAttrs (builtins.functionArgs f) allPkgs) // overrides);
  callPackage = path: makeOverridable (callPackage1 path);
  pkgs = with nixpkgs; rec {
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix nixpkgs;
    hello = callPackage ./hello.nix { };
    local_graphviz = callPackage ./graphviz.nix { };
    graphvizCore = local_graphviz.override { gdSupport = false; };
    graphvizCore2 = graphvizCore.override { gdSupport = false; };
  };
in pkgs
```

Comment: Your definition of `makeOverridable` is wrong.  The document you linked to gives two definitions, one which works recursively and one which does not.  You aren't using either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `makeOverridable` is defined properly using one of the definitions in Nix Pills, you can think of it as a higher-order function: it takes a normal function named `f`, and it changes it into a new function whose results can be overridden.

Assuming you already have a function named `callPackage1`, you can make an overridable version like this:

```
rec {
  callPackage1 = ...;
  callPackage = makeOverridable callPackage1;
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

Actually, `callPackage1` needs a path in order to return the type of function that is expected by `makeOverridable` (a function that takes a set and returns an object to which we can add the override `attribute`).  So let's try this definition of `callPackage`:

```
callPackage = path: makeOverridable (callPackage1 path);
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping me with this. When I implement that I get `error: syntax error, unexpected REC`.

Comment: Would you mind posting the file where the syntax error is happening, either on gist.github.com or by editing your question above?  Is `rec` lowercase, as I wrote it above?  Did you fill in the `...` with an appropriate, syntactically-correct definition of a function?

Comment: I added EDIT 2. `rec` is lowercase as you wrote it. I moved makeOverridable from `lib.nix` to `default.nix` (just copied and pasted) and then included `callPackage1`, and `callPackage` in `rec`.

Comment: You can't just define an unnamed set in the middle of a `let` block.  The Nix language expects you to be defining named variables in a `let` block.  Luckily, `let` blocks behave a lot like recursive sets so you can just remove the `rec {` and the matching `};`, basically just moving those definitions into the `let` block.

Comment: I see. I removed the `rec` wrapper (see above) which fixed that error, but now I get `error: value is a function while a set was expected`

Comment: OK, see EDIT 1 in my answer.

Comment: That worked! I had to add `rec` to `pkgs` and change `graphviz.override` to `local_graphviz.override` otherwise it would spit out an error from the graphviz from `<nixpkgs>`.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  If my answer is satisfactory can you upvote it and click the checkmark to accept it?

Comment: Done! Thanks again. However, I have less than 15 reputation points so my upvote was recorded but doesn't change the publicly displayed score.

Answer (score 2):

I am working through the same Nix Pills and had trouble with the reader exercise in Pill 14.  I found the answers here helpful.

In my solution the argument to makeOverridable is an unnamed function.

```
let
  nixpkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
  allPkgs = nixpkgs // pkgs;
  lib = import ./lib.nix;

  # Function to find arguments of function defined in "path"
  callPackage = path: lib.makeOverridable (overrides:
    { result =
    let f = import path;
        in f (
          (builtins.intersectAttrs (builtins.functionArgs f) allPkgs)
          // overrides
        ); }) {};

  pkgs = with nixpkgs; rec {
    mkDerivation = import ./autotools.nix nixpkgs;
    hello = callPackage ./hello.nix;
    graphviz = callPackage ./graphviz.nix;
    graphvizCore = graphviz.override { gdSupport = false; };
  };

in pkgs
```